# How to push image coordinates in a specific order?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I can select the image coordinates. But I want to select or arrange clicked image coordinates in a specific order in an array that is:

```
[ "top-left" , "top-right" , "bottom-left" , "bottom-right" ]
```

Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/seraphina/images/b/b2/Dragonseraphina.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20160103194957" height="200" width="200" alt="dragon">
```

Below code generate's coordinates on click and push in an array named "coordinates":

```
coordinates = []
     counter = 0
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("img").on("click", function(event) {
          if(counter<4){
                    var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                    var y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;
                    //alert("X Coordinate: " + x + " Y Coordinate: " + y);
                    coordinates.push(x,y)
                    console.log(coordinates)
                    counter++;
                  } 
    });
    });
```

Working demo:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/t03nducb/
```

Comment: Given your image, can you provide what the expected output would be?  Would one of them always be 0,0?   or this.offsetLeft/this.offsetTop?

Comment: And what's the problem with the given code? Anything not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below and identify the quadrant:

```
var coordinates = new Array(4); //<--fixed size
var counter = 0
 
var width = 200;
var height = 200;
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").on("click", function(event) {
      if(counter<4){
                var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                var y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;
                
                if(x < width/2) {
                    if(y < height/2) {
                     coordinates[0] = [x,y];
                     //console.log("top-left"); //<---first quadrant
                  } else {
                     coordinates[2] = [x,y];
                     //console.log("bottom-left");  //<---third quadrant
                  }
                } else {
                    if(y < height/2) {
                     coordinates[1] = [x,y];
                     //console.log("top-right"); //<---second quadrant
                  } else {
                     coordinates[3] = [x,y];
                     //console.log("bottom-right");  //<---fourth quadrant
                  }
                }
                console.log(coordinates)
                counter++;
              } 
});
});
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your solution is working on jsfiddle but not working on my script. If I am selecting top left then coordinates added to bottom left array and selecting for top right then coordinates added to bottom right array

Comment: Could you elaborate, "not working on my script?".  The attached solution gives an idea, how you can achieve your purpose as per the asked question. Could you update the question description, with what you are doing?